# AsyncTask Confusion with abstract

Tags: android

I am a bit new to android programming and cant seem to shake this bug..

It tells me:

```
The type LoginForm.login must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<String,Void,String>.doInBackground(String...)
```

This is the code:

```
private class login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     protected String doInBackground(String url) {
        String response = "";
          DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
          try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
              response += s;
            }

          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return response;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        int mId = 0;

        //Close loading bar and text
        login_form_loader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        warning.setText(result);

      }
    }
```

What exactly does this mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the method signature to:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url)
```

(and you should add the `@Override` annotation on that method too for clarity).

Comment: That works great but now am getting the error: The constructor HttpGet(String[]) is undefined

Comment: Assuming you only pass one string / are only interested in the first string, you can use `new HttpGet(url[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

The doinbackground function should be like this in your case

```
   @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Your code here
        return null;
   }
```